# Can i detect screen size of the client device only with html without any javascript?

Tags: html

I have a specification that i have to detect screen size of the device only with HTML not using any scripting language or css.

Answer (score 1):

No.

That isn't what HTML is for and nobody has stuck an unofficial extension on it to make it possible.

If you want to have a different presentation on different sizes of display then the correct tool to use is [CSS Media Queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries).

Comment: Can i do something in which i can detect the screen size before the page loads and change the content of the page before the page loads?

Comment: So,is that not possible ?